# groovy exception while building presto at 0.229

Tags: groovy, presto

I'm learning presto, and want to run Presto in my IDE.

So I builded presto with "./mvnw clean install -DskipTests", following the instructions in this document: https://github.com/Teradata/presto.

But I encountered an exception as follow

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:3.1.10:spotbugs (spotbugs) on project presto-root: Execution spotbugs of goal com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:3.1.10:spotbugs failed: Unable to load the mojo 'spotbugs' in the plugin 'com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:3.1.10'. A required class is missing: groovy/lang/GroovyObject
```

My version of Presto is tag 0.229.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: I recommend that you join [Presto Community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html). See you there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> following the instructions in this document: https://github.com/Teradata/presto.

This is an obsolete repository.
The team maintaining it left Teradata in 2017 and started Starburst Data company (read more https://www.globenewswire.com/news-release/2017/12/13/1261305/0/en/Starburst-Accelerates-Presto-Adoption-for-Fast-Interactive-Queries-of-Big-Data.html).

In 2019 the team works closely with [Presto Software Foundation](https://trino.io/blog/2019/01/31/presto-software-foundation-launch.html).

Thus, https://github.com/trinodb/trino is the current "home address" to use.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:3.1.10:spotbugs (spotbugs) on project presto-root: Execution spotbugs of goal com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:3.1.10:spotbugs failed: Unable to load the mojo 'spotbugs' in the plugin 'com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:3.1.10'. A required class is missing: groovy/lang/GroovyObject

I have not encountered a problem like that before.

Note that Presto currently recommends Java 8 to build.
You can use e.g. Open JDK, Adopt Open JDK or Azul's distribution.

If more troubleshooting is needed, that isn't really fit for SO question-answer design, I recommend you join the `#dev` channel on [Presto Community slack](https://trino.io/slack.html).